# PHP cURL Function with header

Tags: php, curl

I am getting error with the following code as "{"detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."}" where in i have included the authentication info in the header. Where i am doing wrong.

```
<?php
  $token="43e6c623dda8f35XXXX1fa5f0ec57d58e91154a";
  $wbns="974510010010";
  $headers = array(
      'Authorization: '.$token
    );
  $url="https://test.delhivery.com/api/p/packing_slip?wbns=".$wbns;

    $ch = curl_init();
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
    echo curl_error($ch);
    $return = curl_exec ($ch);
    curl_close ($ch);

    echo $return;
    ?>
```

Comment: will you please help me to find where i am making an error

Comment: Refer also `CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH` on http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php (I'm not sure.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to specify which kind of authorization token it is.

For instance :

```
 $headers = array(
      'Authorization: Basic '.$token
    );
```

or

```
 $headers = array(
      'Authorization: OAuth '.$token
    );
```

etc

Comment: m not sure but the guideline is: curl ­XGET '<host­url>/api/p/packing_slip?wbns=<waybill>,<waybill>' ­H 'Authorization: Token <token>'    and the parameters for header is:
Accept: application/json
Authorization ­ Token

Comment: Then in the array try '`Authorization: Token '.$token`